# converting non-conformable multi-layer rasters to a data frame

Tags: r

I want to create a big data frame from all rasters which are from all folders. All rasters share the same properties such as rain etc. and same x&y in the same folder, but they don't share same x&y with rasters with the other folders. For example, If I have rain and temperature rasters in fifty folders, these two rasters will share the same x&y in the same folder but they don't share the same x&y with other folders, in this case, I need to put them in one big stack and then convert them to df. I want to do it in this way because I want to use random forest to predict some of the properties based on others.

** Each raster has one layer.
** I want to know which row came from which rasters
In short, I want a data frame of x, y & value for all layers of all rasters which share same x&y in each folder but not with others from other folders.

Here are the codes:

```
    Reading <- function(raster) {
  df <- stack(raster)
}

All_raster <- dir("E:/50_folders/", recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE, pattern=".tif$")# This is to read rasters from 50 folders
All_tif <- sapply(All_raster, Reading)
ALl_tif <- as.data.frame(All_tif , xy =TRUE)
```

And this is the error I get Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : cannot coerce class ‘structure("RasterStack", package = "raster")’ to a data.frame

Answer (score 1):

`sapply` returns a list, so in your case its returning a list of stacks. This code demonstrates your situation and reproduces your error:

```
> r = raster(matrix(1:12,3,4))
> s = stack(r,r,r)
> all_s = list(s,s,s,s)
> as.data.frame(all_s)
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class "structure("RasterStack", package = "raster")" to a data.frame
>
```

To fix, stack the stacks into a bigger stack:

```
> one_stack = stack(all_s)
> head(as.data.frame(one_stack,xy=TRUE))
      x         y layer.1.1 layer.2.1 layer.3.1 layer.1.2 layer.2.2 layer.3.2
1 0.125 0.8333333         1         1         1         1         1         1
2 0.375 0.8333333         4         4         4         4         4         4
3 0.625 0.8333333         7         7         7         7         7         7
[etc]
```

Also unless you are planning on doing some preprocessing in your `Reading` function, you can call `stack` on the vector of TIFF paths (`stack(All_raster)`)  to get a big stack with no need to loop over anything.

Comment: This is what I get now, because each folder has rasters with different extents  and origins. Error in compareRaster(rasters) : different extent

Comment: If you are getting that error then all your rasters *dont* share the same X and Y. You said in your question that they did.

Comment: Yes, but is there any way to fix that?

Comment: What output do you want? A data frame of x,y,value for all layers of all rasters?

Comment: I meant they share same x and y in each folder. Sorry I should make it clear.

Comment: I want to create a big data frame from all rasters which are from all folders. There will be fifty-row names which share the same properties such as rain etc., but they have different x&y. For example, If I have rain and temperature rasters in fifty folders and these two rasters will share the same x&y in the same folder but they don't share the same x&y with other folders, in this case, I need to but them in one big stack and then convert them to df. In this case, rasters will be repeated fifty times under one column. Is that clear now? Thank you so much

Comment: You need to edit your question and add all this information, change the question title to something more than just "looping over rasters" (maybe "converting non-conformable multi-layer rasters to a data frame") and show some descriptions of the inputs and outputs.

Comment: Yes, I want a data frame of x, y & value for all layers of all rasters.

Comment: And each raster is a single layer? And do you care about indentifying which row came from which rasters? There's a lot of questions. Please edit your question to clarify all this, since I'll probably have to delete this answer since it doesn't seem to answer your actual question any more.